# How to create a many-to-many relation between two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, relationship

I have been designing a new database for my project. I have created a table `tbl_packgage` and another `tbl_testinfo`. What I want to achieve is that one package can contain multiple tests with them. And one test can be associate with multiple packages at the same time. I have done some workaround but still not been able to find out what I'm looking for exactly. Please check the table snap shot mentioned below :

[image: Package Table]

[image: Test Table]

Kindly tell me how can I achieve the required functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need a third table that contains the relationships between the two tables using the primary keys from both tables.

An example of what the table would look like...

```
 Package_id | Test_id
 1            2
 1            5
 5            2
 6            3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a third table `info_dependencys` where you have 2 fields `test_id` and `package_id`.
Then use a [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: i have also thought about this but i want to know is this the only way to achieve this functionality ??

Comment: If we want to use a normalized database, yes @NitinSingh. Sure you can hack something like an array into a `BLOP`, but this is realy code mess.

Comment: @NitinSingh, whoy on earth would you not want to use the 3rd table?

Comment: Is it the ONLY imaginable way? No. It is the right way? Yes.